# Array in view mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an array of bytes in my model

```
public byte[] created_dt { get; set; }
```

It represents a timestamp value in the database.

In my view , I am referring it as `@model.created_dt`

but it is coming as `system.byte[]`

How to resolve this?

Comment: You need to run with for/ forech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as this is just an example to achieve the functionality

```
 @foreach(var a in model.created_dt){
    <label>@a</label>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the behavior, this looks like ASP.NET and you are simply seeing the output of an implicit call to `ToString()` on the array (the default way of displaying anything that does not have a template defined). You will have to do something *with* the raw byte data and present it to the user.

Since you refer to "timestamp" and the property name might suggest a record creation time, you may want to write a helper method to translate this raw data to a `DateTime` which you could then format accordingly.

However, one of the following is most likely true:

1. It strikes me as odd that you are using raw binary to store what should otherwise be a `datetime2` column. (Or it *is* a datetime in your database but you're doing something unorthodox to retrieve the value.)
2. Your property/column name of "created_dt" is a misnomer and it is really a `timestamp` (i.e. `rowversion`) column. In which case I don't think this is something a user would know what to do with, and it probably doesn't belong on the UI.